# How do I resolve "unresolvable reference to 'Composite'" using Eclipse/WindowBuilder?

Tags: java, windowbuilder

Trying to setup my first Java environment and give it a go and immediately running into issues.

"No proposals have been found to fix the unresolvable reference to 'Composite'"

I read this post

https://www.bitdegree.org/tutorials/how-to-code-in-java/

installed JDK 16 and Eclipse 2021

Installed Window Builder via Help - Install ...

Then started following the steps in this video to create a new Hello World example: https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/

but I get stuck right around where the video is at on 0:37 seconds

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After dealing with this problem myself, I've finally come to a resolution! I understand that it's been a while since you asked this question, but hopefully if someone else has the issue they can come across this instead of busting their head over figuring it out.

After generating the composite file, where it says
"import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;"

Bring up the quick fixes menu and select
"Add 'requires org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64' to module-info.java"

Then head over to the module-info.java file, and on the newly-generated requires statement, select the quick fix
"Move classpath entry 'org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64... to modulepath"
This immediately resolved all of the issues for me.